# How to debug PHP application in Google Cloud Workstations

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-workstations

Currently I use Google `Cloud Shell Editor` as my chosen IDE.  I like the code editor based on VS Code, and also like the persistent 5GB home directory. This allows me to install PHP on the home directory, which in turn means that I can run my app using the command `php -S localhost:8080`

Recently I heard about [Google Cloud Workstations](https://cloud.google.com/workstations) which provides multi-IDE support, including a version of VS Code called "Code-OSS". I would like to start using the Cloud Workstations as my IDE, but the one thing holding me back is PHP.  I don't know how to debug a PHP application using Google Cloud Workstations which run in the browser.

How can I run my PHP applications in Google Cloud Workstations which run in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're familiar with VS Code, the look and feel is very similar. I've managed to run `php -S localhost:8080` using Google Workstations by updating and upgrading my packages first:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then I install PHP afterwards:

```
sudo apt-get install php
```

Right now I'm using the latest PHP version (`PHO 7.4.30`) but you can use your preferred version using this [link](https://www.tecmint.com/install-different-php-versions-in-ubuntu/) as your reference.

Let me know if this worked out for you.

Comment: I followed these steps and PHP was installed on the Cloud Workstation, but then after a shutdown and relaunch the PHP installation was missing.  Why would it be missing?  I thought that anything I added would persist.

Comment: Based on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/workstations/docs), it's still in pre-GA terms, meaning some functions may or may not work as intended as they are not yet feature-complete. I also encountered some hiccups while testing some projects. I would suggest using this link to [file a bug or feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: Since the Persistent Disk is attached to the workstation's `home` folder, I'm guessing that maybe I need to install PHP in the `home` folder rather than the default location.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve created a Dockerfile using Google base image with Code-OSS and installing all the libraries that I need, including nginx on port 8080.

In this way I can both use the IDE and run the application on the same workstation and it works like a charm.

Comment: I would be interested to see the Dockerfile you are using.